# How to find out the name of a variable Customize is customizing

Tags: customize, variables

I'd like to have a function that when run from within a `Customize` buffer will return the name of the variable that would be customized at point.

Comment: [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Inserting_Text_from_Cursor) has key `M-.`, which inserts text at the cursor into the minibuffer. In Customize, with variable names expressed as in Lisp, `C-h v M-.` puts the variable name in the minibuffer, but the final `:` is included (because it has symbol syntax), so you need to hit Backspace, to remove that char before hitting `RET`.

Comment: `info-lookup-guess-custom-symbol` from info-look.el?

Comment: ```info-lookup-guess-custom-symbol``` seems to guess wrong for me.  Example: ```M-x customize-group magit-commands```, with point on the ```M``` in ```Magit No Confirm```, evaluating ```(info-lookup-guess-custom-symbol)``` returns ```"-Magit-No-"```, which is wrong.  The actual variable name is ```magit-no-confirm```.  It's not a bad guess, but it's not what I'm looking for.  I'm looking for the exact variable name I can feed in to ```setq```

Comment: Set option `custom-unlispify-tag-names` to `nil`, so Customize shows the Lisp value, not an English version of its name.

Comment: Maybe file a bug report for `info-lookup-guess-custom-symbol`: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. It's essentially undoing the effect of non-`nil` `custom-unlispify-tag-names`.  Sounds like it's not doing it perfectly.